# Scheduled for permanent deletion during the next cleanup job in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

Recently we have migrated TFS 2017 to Azure devops 2019.We are seeing the below screenshot message like "Scheduled for permanent deletion during the next cleanup job" in some of the recycle bin build pipelines.
What does it mean? where this cleanup job maintained.

[image]

Comment: When I delete a build, I can see the following message: Scheduled for permanent deletion in 29 days. Have you always seen such a message? Can you try to restore the build and delete it again?

Comment: I think these jobs are came from old TFS server after migrating it showing like that .If i delete in new version server its showing some number.

Answer (score 0):

> What does it mean? where this cleanup job maintained.

That means that the deleted release pipeline in the recycle bin will be deleted after the Retention policy expires. Before that, Azure devops will keep it so that we can restore it.

You could go to the `Project Settings`-> `Release retention`:

[image]

Comment: Liu-MSFT Its not showing any number. Its showing "Scheduled for permanent deletion during the next cleanup job"

Comment: @PravallikaPotnuru, Would you please share the info about your Retention policy settings? And have you test it with Azure devops services? I could not reproduce this with Azure devops Server 2019

Comment: @Liu-MSFT           Retention policy settings
Days to retain a release 
30  
                                                                                                                                       the builds that we are deleting in azure devops server 2019 (currently running)are showing 30 days as per retention policy, but before migrating we deleted some builds and those builds are shown as "Scheduled for permanent deletion during the next cleanup job"  in the current running server

Comment: Retention policy settings Days to retain a release 30 the builds that we are deleting in azure devops server 2019 (currently running)are showing 30 days as per retention policy, but before migrating we deleted some builds and those builds are shown as "Scheduled for permanent deletion during the next cleanup job" in the current running server

Comment: @PravallikaPotnuru, This is normal. When you delete the pipeline in TFS, this information will not be completely saved in the pipeline and migrate to Azure devops.

Answer (score 0):

Its not showing any number. Its showing "Scheduled for permanent deletion during the next cleanup job"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03FNn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03FNn.png)

Comment: Just update your question directly instead of posting an answer for the update info.